# Share folder with mac guest on a linux ubuntu host

Tags: virtualbox, sharing, mac

I am trying to share a folder on VirtualBox with a guest OS X, I tried to share the folder through VirtualBox but it doesn't show up in OS X. I also tried sharing a folder on OS X and access it from Ubuntu also failed.

So I need someone who did this before with success to tell me how to correctly do this.

Comment: Stupid question to check the obvious... did you install Guest Additions on the guest?

Comment: Not its not stupid, yes I installed Guest Additions on the guest go look it up on Google every one is having trouble with this guest additions isn't compatible with snow leopard ... if you don't know you don't have to comment and disrespect people

Comment: @bhappy VirtualBox Guest Additions for Mac doesn't exist. But his comment wasn't supposed to be rude.

Comment: @Vortico VirtualBox has Guest Additions for Mac (marked *initial support*) as of version 6 ([changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog))

Answer (score 5):

As per http://www.sysprobs.com/mac-os-guest-virtualbox-326-snow-leopard-1064-windows-7-32-bit

1. Set up Samba on your Ubuntu host file sharing (it should be easy now, I use edited smb.conf but I am sure there is a much easier way now).
2. On you mac guest, go>connect to network and enter smb://ip_of_your_host and then connect (either using guest or login/pass - depends on your Samba setup)
3. Create an alias na put it on desktop for easy use.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem - solved it by installing a the "samba" server on Linux. Since then I am flawlessly able to access my folders.
(Ok, it would be nicer to directly use VB's shared folder option ...)

System: Debian 6.0
Virtualbox: 4.1
Mac OS X: 10.6.6

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual of VirtualBox, no Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time. So the `Shared Folder` function is unavailable.

[image]

**Solution**

Like the @cpb and @sup gived. Using `samba` to serve your shared folder.

**References**

- Chapter 14. Known limitations, https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html

Answer (score 0):

Mount manually your folder, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo mkdir /media/vbox
sudo mount -t vboxsf "yoursharedfolder" /media/vbox
```

If you want it mounted automatically every start, run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

In the text editor window that opens, and add this as the last line:

```
mount -t vboxsf "yoursharedfolder" /media/vbox
```

Comment: I suppose it should also work in `fstab`.

Comment: I don't know with what to replace "yoursharedfolder". I want to share my folder /home/tresipunt/Descargas but how is it called inside the mac guest?? thks

Comment: This is a description of how to access VirtualBox shared folders on a Linux guest.  But the question is about a Mac guest.  So this doesn't answer the question.